# What is the best approach to do dynamic layout in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, layout

My main view should be splited to 3 regions,
every region should contain a view, and...

**their placemants should be switched on run time**.

What is the best (easiest, generic, maintainable) approach to do this dynamic layout in WPF ?

[image]

Comment: Grid or DockPanel. What have you tried? Where is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/) control.

> AvalonDock is a docking windows control for WPF that lets you create
>   customizable layouts using a full featured window docking system
>   similar to what is found in many popular integrated development
>   environements (IDEs) such as Visual Studio. It includes themes and
>   samples to get you started.

[Here](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AvalonDock%202.0%20Getting%20Start%20Guide&referringTitle=Documentation) you can find documentation.

On the codeproject.com is 5-part tutorial series about AvalonDock [2.0]:

1. [AvalonDock [2.0] Tutorial Part 1 - Adding a Tool Window](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483507/AvalonDock-Tutorial-Part-Adding-a-Tool-Windo)
2. [AvalonDock [2.0] Tutorial Part 2 - Adding a Start Page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483533/AvalonDock-2-0-Tutorial-Part-2-Adding-a-Start-Page)
3. [AvalonDock [2.0] Tutorial Part 3 - AvalonEdit in AvalonDock](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570313/AvalonDock-2-0-Tutorial-Part-3-AvalonEdit-in-Avalo)
4. [AvalonDock [2.0] Tutorial Part 4 - Integrating AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570324/AvalonDock-2-0-Tutorial-Part-4-Integrating-AvalonE)
5. [AvalonDock [2.0] Tutorial Part 5 - Load/Save Layout with
   De-Referenced DockingManager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/719143/AvalonDock-2-0-Tutorial-Part-5-Load-Save-Layout-wi)